# Piwik delete custom variable

Tags: matomo

I was messing around in my dev instance of Piwik with custom variables and put in some garbage values. I want to delete these from Piwik but I can not find a way to do this. Does anyone know how to delete a custom variable from Piwik?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2):

To delete custom variable:

```
deleteCustomVariable (index, scope )
```

http://piwik.org/docs/javascript-tracking/#toc-custom-variables

Update: Sorry I misread. To get it out of your DB, you will have to do some MYSQL Surgery. Look for:

```
custom_var_k - holds key (name of your variable) 
custom_var_v - holds the actual value
```

Comment: After deleting the custom vars, remember do invalidate and rearchive reports. See http://piwik.org/faq/how-to/faq_155/